# Understand Inference process in TensorFlow-Lite

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow-lite, inference

I am new to tensorflow lite development and would like to know a guide to understand the code of inference process of any neural network in tflite.

How can I proceed?

Thanks in advance

I have tried to follow the inference flow for a dense neural network.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference) to know what APIs does what and follow from there.

Some high level points

To load TF Lite file you use TfLite Interpreter.
A TFLite graph consists of a list of subgraphs (basically each subgraph can be viewed as a function).

Each subgraph should have operations in execution order and calling Invoke will trigger them in the provided order.